# MAUI EntryHandler does not contain EntryMapper

Tags: maui

The code below was working until around preview 11 of Maui. But with preview 13 I get a compiler error: *'EntryHandler' does not contain a definition for 'EntryMapper'*.

A similar error is shown for PickerMapper.

The code has been copied from the official documentation.

```
#if ANDROID
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
#endif
using Application = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application;

namespace myapp;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(AuthenticationService authenticationService, SyncService syncService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Remove underline from all pickers and entries in app
#if ANDROID
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.PickerMapper.AppendToMapping("NoUnderline", (h, v) =>
        {
            h.NativeView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToAndroid());
        });
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.EntryMapper.AppendToMapping("NoUnderline", (h, v) =>
        {
            h.NativeView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToAndroid());
        });
#endif
        MainPage = new AppShell(authenticationService, syncService);
    }
}
```

Anyone who sees the solution?

I have been searching high and low, but the consensus seems to be that the code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all the `EntryMapper` and `PickerMapper`, basically all `{Control}Mapper` got renamed to just `Mapper`.

Additionally, I see you have references to `NativeView` whenever you upgrade to preview 14, those will be renamed to `PlatformView` so you will have to rename those accordingly as well.